# Javafx save textField to a text file

Tags: java, javafx

I have this code for saving to a text file however, I can't seem to find a way to make it save to not the user.home folder but to another folder on my hard drive. I searched in many places but couldn't really find anything that could help me.

It works with the user.home setting but if I try to change it, it doesn't. The program, when executed, comes up with Source not found.

```
saveBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            String s = null;
            //Variable to display text read from file
            if (_clickMeMode) {
                FileOutputStream out = null;
                try {
                //Code to write to file
                String text = titleField.getText();
                byte b[] = text.getBytes();
                String outputFileName = System.getProperty("user.home"
                    + File.separatorChar+"home")
                    + File.separatorChar + "Movies2.txt";
                    out = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
                    out.write(b);
                    out.close();
                    //Clear text field
                    titleField.setText("");
            }catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Cannotss text.txt");
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Cannote");
            }
            }
            }
            else 
            {
                //Save text to file
                _clickMeMode = true;
            }                       
        window.setTitle("Main Screen");
        window.setScene(mainScreen);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So what actually happens when you try to save to a different folder? "It doesn't work" is not a very useful description of a problem.

Comment: The program, when executed, comes up with Source not found.

Comment: Do you have such property name when u change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file name is incorrectly assigned:

```
String outputFileName = System.getProperty("user.home"
    + File.separatorChar+"home")
    + File.separatorChar + "Movies2.txt";
```

You are passing a string of the form `"user.home/home"` to `System.getProperty()`.

Since there is no such property, this will return `null`.

Then you concatenate this with `/Movies2.txt`, so `outputFileName` will be something like `null/Movies2.txt`.

(A simple `System.out.println(outputFileName)` will confirm this.)

---

Instead of building the filename by hand like this, you should use a higher-level API to do it. E.g.:

```
Path outputFile = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "home", "Movies2.txt");
OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(outputFile);
out.write(b);
```

If you also need (or might need) to create the directory, you can do

```
Path outputDir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "home");
Files.createDirectories(outputDir);
Path outputFile = outputDir.resolve("Movies2.txt");
OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(outputFile);
out.write(b);
```